# How to move specific game objects with tags based on mouse click?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a 3D model that is made up of 6 kids of game objects and i want to be able to click on each individual parts of the model and have that part move in a certain direction and then click on it again and it returns to its original position. I gave each individual part with a tag and a box collider I intend to have them move when I click on the object with the collider and the different tag. I saw that raycasting helps, so i implemented that too. I just want to be put in the right direction. Here's what I have so far:

```
public class AlconPartMover : MonoBehaviour {

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hit;
        Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit);
        if (other.gameObject.tag== "Back")
        {
            transform.Translate(5 * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
        }
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "BackAni")
        {
            transform.Translate(0, 0, 5 * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "FrontAni")
        {
            transform.Translate(5 * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
        }
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "FrontStill")
        {
            transform.Translate(0, 0, 5 * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "TopStill")
        {
            transform.Translate(0, 5 * Time.deltaTime, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? It looks like you're off to a good start.

Comment: My question is how do i get it to react to my click to move and then move back to its regular position once it has moved to its first position?

Comment: Unfortunately we're not here to write the code for you. You're off to a good start, but you need to show us what you've tried and we can help you from there.

Comment: I've made a couple of adjustments, is translate the proper method to use?

Comment: Your raycast code must be done in the `Update` function not the `OnTriggerEnter` function. Please use `Debug.Log` to debug your code before making a post so that you'll know where exactly you need help. Just by looking at your code, you need to watch Unity tutorial before moving forward with your game. See [here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials) for more information. Just pick one project tutorial that's very similar to what you are making, finish it and that should get you started with Unity

Comment: @Programmer It's even better if the raycast is done in the FixedUpdate, so it will be synchronized with unity physics